# Should I use plates or plate when I say "both plate and bowl are dishes"?

Tags: word-usage

This [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6283/373332) gives a excellent explanation about the difference between dish and plate

> A plate is a specific type of dish... The other common type of dish is a bowl.

to make a conclusion, should I use **plates** or **plate** when I say "both plate and bowl are dishes"?

Comment: You need, “Both plates and bowls are dishes.” You mean *all* plates and *all* bowls so they are both plurals.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Orbital Aussie.  "You need,

> "Both plates and bowls are dishes.

"You mean all plates and all bowls so they are both plurals."

As a side note, in some regions of the United States (at least), “plates” and “dishes” are synonymous. “Please hand me a dish” is taken to mean “please hand me a plate.”  For many, a bowl is never considered a dish; it’s always a bowl.

Comment: Hello Gregory. It would be good to repeat Orbital Aussie's response.  Comments, like the one Orbital made are "second class" here and get routinely deleted.  If and when Orbital's comment is deleted, your answer won't make much sense. It good to say "As Orbital Aussie said in a comment ' .... '. "  I've edited for this.